# Element has no widget of type 'Serenity.EnumEditor'!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, serenity-platform

I'm building an application for Student Information System using serenity platform. In the dashboard I've one widget showing number of active students, when click on "More info" I want to display only the active students, I got the below error: "Element has no widget of type 'Serenity.EnumEditor'!"

I've followed the same steps as the Northwind order example but no success:

```
protected ESTS_CODEFilter: Serenity.EnumEditor;

 protected createQuickFilters(): void {
            super.createQuickFilters();
            let fld = Students.EnrollmentRow.Fields;
            this.ESTS_CODEFilter = this.findQuickFilter(Serenity.EnumEditor, fld.ESTS_CODE);
        }

public set_ESTS_CODE(value: string): void {
            this.ESTS_CODEFilter.value = value == null ? '' : value;
        }
```

In the StudentsIndex.cshtml page I've the below code to get the query string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        var EnrollGrid = new Portal.Students.EnrollmentGrid($('#GridDiv'), {});

        var q = Q.parseQueryString();
        console.log(q.ESTS_CODE);
        if (q.ESTS_CODE != null && q.ESTS_CODE.length) {

            EnrollGrid.set_ESTS_CODE(q.ESTS_CODE);
        }
        Q.initFullHeightGridPage($('#GridDiv'));
    });

</script>
```

Any idea how to define a widget of type Serenity.EnumEditor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a EnumEditor there? Not a LookupEditor?

```
protected createQuickFilters(): void {
            super.createQuickFilters();
            let fld = Students.EnrollmentRow.Fields;

            this.ESTS_CODEFilter = this.findQuickFilter(Serenity.LookupEditor, fld.ESTS_CODE);
        }
```

Comment: Actually it's LookupEditor, I've tried to change it to LookupEditor,  but got: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined in                                         public set_ESTS_CODE(value: string): void {
            this.ESTS_CODEFilter.value = value == null ? '' : value;
        }

Comment: How I can set the query value to LookupEditor? I know how to set initial value, but not a query string value.

Comment: Take code that reads it from query string and sets quick filter value into createQuickFilters

Comment: I've done that, but getting "Cannot set property 'value' of undefined" when try to set the query string value to : public set_ESTS_CODE(value: string): void {
            this.ESTS_CODEFilter.value = value == null ? '' : value;
        }

Comment: the code is here https://jsfiddle.net/mhussein/8otr5ryk/ please review and let me know what I should change.

Comment: Not working, when console this.ESTS_CODEFilter  it shows the value as blank ''. for some reasons it's not taking the query string value.

Comment: $Serenity_LookupEditor$5$ OnInitNewEntityField: null$cascadeLink: $type$multiple: falsecascadeField: "TERM_CODE" cascadeFrom: "TERM_CODE" cascadeValue: "161710" element: jQuery.fn.init[1]filterField: undefinedfilter Value: undefineditem ById: Objectitems: Array[6] lastCreateTerm: nulloptions: ObjectpageSize: 100uniqueName: "Serenity_LookupEditor6" value: "" values: Array[0]widgetName: "Serenity_LookupEditor"__proto__: $Serenity_LookupEditorBase

Comment: I've fixed this by creating many xxxxFilter.ts for each case using the initial filter getQuickFilters, it works fine but too much to do:( protected getQuickFilters(): Serenity.QuickFilter<Serenity.Widget<any>, any>[] {
            let filters = super.getQuickFilters();
            let fld = Students.EnrollmentRow.Fields;

            Q.first(filters, x => x.field == fld.ESTS_CODE).init = w => {
                (w as Serenity.EnumEditor).value = 'NA';
            };
            return filters;
        }